# show images on screen by using urls

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have urls of images from flicker and I want to show them on screen but I can't get any images.

Here is my code:

```
loadimages(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({spinner:true});
  console.log('spinner');
  //  axios.get(`https://www.pexels.com/`).then(res=>{
  //    console.log(this.state.spinner);
  //    this.setState({images:res.data,spinner:false});
  //  });

  axios.get( "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=kitten&format=json&nojsoncallback=true" ) 
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('hellodata', response.data.items);
      this.setState({
        images: response.data.items,
        spinner:false
      });
      console.log('images', this.state.images);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log(err);
    })
}

render() {
  const mappedStorage = this.state.images.map((item) => <li>{item.media.m}</li>)
  return (
    <div className="fun2">
      {this.state.spinner ?
        <div>
          <MDSpinner size={50}/>
        </div>
      : null
      }

      {/* <ul>{mappedStorage} */}
      <ul>
        <img src={mappedStorage} />
      </ul>
      <button onClick={this.loadimages}>
        Click Here
      </button> 
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is a sample response from the API:

```
{
  "title": "Recent Uploads tagged kitten",
  "link": "https://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/kitten/",
  "description": "",
  "modified": "2018-11-13T13:31:05Z",
  "generator": "https://www.flickr.com",
  "items": [
        {
          "title": "flo_02-10-06 001",
          "link": "https://...",
          "media": {
            "m": "https://....jpg"
          },
          "date_taken": "2018-11-13T12:09:32-08:00",
          "description": "......"
          "published": "2018-11-13T11:11:06Z",
          "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"nikita zenon2\")",
          "author_id": "125437611@N07",
          "tags": "some tags here"
        },
        {
          "title": "flo_02-10-06 002",
          "link": "https://...",
          "media": {
            "m": "https://....jpg"
          },
          "date_taken": "2018-11-13T12:09:32-08:00",
          "description": "......"
          "published": "2018-11-13T11:11:06Z",
          "author": "nobody@flickr.com (\"nikita zenon2\")",
          "author_id": "125437611@N07",
          "tags": "some tags here"
        },
```

I get urls but now I don't now how to show images on screen, maybe by using map function. If you know, please let me know. I'm new in ReactJs.

Thanks

Comment: You need to return the items as mapped to image, or return the first element of the array then it’ll work with your current code `mappedSttorage = this.state.images.pop();`

Comment: dont got u:(...

Comment: What you’re doing is mapping all the elements of array to its string url. Either get one of them and pass it to src of image or instead of mapping to URL map it to an JSX image.

Comment: Basically instead you should do this  `<li><im src={item.media.m} /></li>`

Comment: It was very interesting to see the info on the api url you provided in your question. Next time, try to show us a basic sample data, and avoid private info or private urls the no one needs to see.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there actually, you just need to nest your `img` tags inside of the `li` tags.

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

render() {
    const mappedStorage = this.state.images.map((item) => <li><img src={item.media.m} /></li>)
    return (
       <div className="fun2">
          {this.state.spinner?
               <div>
                    <MDSpinner  size={50}/>
               </div>
           :null}

           <ul>{mappedStorage}<ul>

           <button onClick={this.loadimages}>
                Click Here
           </button> 
      </div>
    );
}
```